# Fill default value based on logged in user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am defining a new table where a column suppose to store name of the logged in user. How to grab logged in user name as default value for a column? Is it possible out of the box ?

Comment: If you use a single login for your application you don't. The only way this is going to even get started is if every user has their own sql login.

Comment: Authentication is integrated with windows account (integrated security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SYSTEM_USER` variable to fill that.

Comment: I was looking at only user name but this gives me domain/user name. I don't really mind having in your way. But to keep data consistency I had to.

Comment: You can trim domain name off using system functions. I guess that's quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ORIGINAL_LOGIN in case there is some impersonation going on. It will always get the user name that initiated the connection.

[ORIGINAL_LOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx)

[SYSTEM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

Comment: ORIGINAL_LOGIN give value as 'dbo'. CURRENT_USER give value as 'dbo' and finally SYSTEM_USER give value as 'domain/user name'. It is not end of the world and I can write a UDF to get what I wanted. However, just wondering whether there any available out of the box. Thanks